# How to use a web service WCF to connect SQL database to a Java FrontEnd

Tags: database, visual-studio, wcf

For a university project we have to make a car repair workshop, that sends an email to the client when the car is repaired, it has a database in SQL and a webservice WCF, use of RabbitMQ(optional), and a frontend (in either java or other language not from Visual Studio).

my question is how to connect a web service WCF to a database(SQL).

[WCF service example](https://i.stack.imgur.com/UZcMQ.png)

[FrontEnd in windowsForms as an example](https://i.stack.imgur.com/skO91.png)

[SQL database](https://i.stack.imgur.com/RppuP.png)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

At first, you can call WCF service in your `Winform` application, then WCF can use `ORM` framework to connect the PostgreSQL.
You can refer to the below document to call a WCF service.
https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/framework/wcf/accessing-services-using-a-wcf-client
We either use Adding service reference dialog to generate a client proxy or `SVCutil.exe` to generate a client proxy and then call the method like what we call a method locally.
https://learn.microsoft.com/zh-cn/dotnet/framework/wcf/how-to-use-a-wcf-client
Second, the `ORM` framework can help the project connect and manage PostgreSQL. We can use Npgsql for Ado.net driver or entity framework to complete this, Ado.net and Entity framework are two different technology frameworks to manage the database.
https://www.npgsql.org/index.html
Feel free to let me know if there is anything I can help with.